# ng-repeat and value of object

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having a problem with these labels.

I have an arrangement with certain information, including longitude and latitude of this I markers within a map. To click on any of them want to show information from each of these markers. The problem is that it does not recognize the values of my arrangement.

my array :

```
$scope.views = [
  {
      id : 0,
      nombre : 'Problema con cableado',
      fecha : '18/05/2014 a las 15:17',
      estado : 'En revisión',
      latitud : -33.3995448,
      longitud : -70.5705277,
      img : 'img/cables.JPG',
      comentario : 'Exiten problemas en el cableado, estan sueltos y es peligroso. Concurre mucha gente por ese lugar.',
      like : 1,
      like_me : true,
      icono : 'icon ion-android-favorite', 
      clase : 'label_estado label-warning'
  },
  {
      id : 1,
      nombre : 'Poste en mal estado',
      fecha : '09/11/2013 a las 20:45',
      estado : 'Solucionado',
      latitud : -33.4024754,
      longitud : -70.5919616,
      img : 'img/poste.jpeg',
      comentario : 'El poste esta a punto de caer, se encuentra en una calle muy concurrida por personas y automóviles.',
      like : 5,
      like_me : true,
      icono:'icon ion-android-favorite', 
      clase : 'label_estado label-success'
  },
  {
      id : 2,
      nombre : 'Cañeria rota',
      estado : 'Falta información',
      fecha : '03/03/2012 a las 12:13',
      latitud : -33.406975,
      longitud : -70.57283,
      img : 'img/caneria.jpg',
      comentario : 'Esta rota y oxidada, corre agua por todo el lugar.',
      like : 0,
      like_me : false,
      icono : 'icon ion-android-favorite-outline', 
      clase : 'label_estado label-info'

  }
];
```

My html :

```
<ion-content class="map-container">
      <map center="{{latitud}}, {{longitud}}" zoom="12" id="map_views" data-tap-disabled="true">
          <div id="class"  data-tap-disabled="true" ng-repeat="view in views">
              <marker position="{{view.latitud}}, {{view.longitud}}" on-click="verInfo({{view}})" data-tap-disabled="true"/>
          </div>
      </map>
```

function :

```
$scope.verInfo = function(view){
  $ionicPopup.show({
     title: 'Información View',
     subTitle: '',
     content: '<p>Nombre : '+view.nombre+'</p><p>Estado : '+view.estado+'</p><p>Fecha : '+view.fecha+'</p><img src='+view.img+'>',
     buttons: [
               {
                text: 'Ok',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(e) {

                }
              },
            ]
      })
   }
```

Undefined receive only data and not understand why.

** EDIT **

I realized that if data arrive, but arrive out of order and not as I declare. For example:

```
<ion-content class="map-container">
          <map center="{{latitud}}, {{longitud}}" zoom="12" id="map_views" data-tap-disabled="true">
              <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers" data-tap-disabled="true">
                  <marker position="{{marker.latitud}}, {{marker.longitud}}" on-click="verInfo(marker.nombre,marker.fecha,marker.estado)" data-tap-disabled="true"/>
              </div>
          </map>
        </ion-content>
```

OUTPUT :

```
kq {latLng: rf, gb: undefined, pixel: undefined, pa: undefined, stop: function} console-via-logger.js:173
Poste en mal estado console-via-logger.js:173
09/11/2013 a las 20:45
```

This is quite rare, I have no idea because they will be producing.

Comment: you probably want `on-click=verInfo(view)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `on-click` to get function working (without interpolation directive `{{}}`).

```
<div id="class"  data-tap-disabled="true" ng-repeat="view in views">
    <marker position="{{view.latitud}}, {{view.longitud}}" on-click="verInfo(view)" data-tap-disabled="true"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @sioesi did you try `on-click=verInfo(view)`?

Comment: Click works, but the data still do not appear and now I came out this error. GET file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/9282A2D7-6CFE-4E3F-BC81-572F0D400D9A/View.app/www/undefined The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: No, I'm desarollando to my cell phone, send me on my cell that mistake. It's rare that happens, that will not work ng-click? I'm trying to make a codepen.

Comment: I have not been able to generate a codepen, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can do is this:

```
<ion-content class="map-container">
          <map center="{{latitud}}, {{longitud}}" zoom="12" id="map_views" data-tap-disabled="true">
              <div id="class" data-tap-disabled="true" ng-repeat="view in views">
                  <marker ng-repeat="marker in view" position="{{marker.latitud}}, {{marker.longitud}}" on-click="verInfo(marker,marker)" data-tap-disabled="true"/>
              </div>
          </map>
        </ion-content>
```

And also change the format of my array now JSON

```
$scope.views = {
   "values": [
        {
           "id": 0,
           "nombre": "Problema con cableado",
           "fecha": "18/05/2014 a las 15:17",
           "latitud": -33.399544,
           "longitud": -70.570526,
           "img": "img/cables.JPG",
           "estado": "En revisión",
           "clase": "label_estado label-warning",
           "comentario": "Exiten problemas en el cableado, estan sueltos y es peligroso. Concurre mucha gente por ese lugar."
        },

        {
         "id": 1,
         "nombre": "Poste en mal estado",
         "fecha": "09/11/2013 a las 20:45",
         "latitud": -33.402477,
         "longitud": -70.591965,
         "img": "img/poste.jpeg",
         "estado": "Solucionado",
         "clase": "label_estado label-success",
         "comentario": "El poste esta a punto de caer, se encuentra en una calle muy concurrida por personas y automóviles."
      },

      {
         "id": 2,
         "nombre": "Cañeria rota",
         "fecha": "03/03/2012 a las 12:13",
         "latitud": -33.406975,
         "longitud": -70.57283,
         "img": "img/caneria.jpg",
         "estado": "Falta información",
         "clase": "label_estado label-info",
         "comentario": "Esta rota y oxidada, corre agua por todo el lugar."
      }

   ]

}
```